# Android Facebook SDK: what does "implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'" mean?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

It is written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/upgrade-guide/) that I should use the following version of the Android Facebook SDK:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
```

But I see [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases) that the last version of the Facebook Android SDK is the version 16.

So, should I use:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
```

or:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:16.0.0'
```

to get the last version of the SDK ???

Thanks !

Comment: `[8,9)` = any version starting with 8 (including) up to 9 (excluding) => `8.x`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html

Comment: Thanks. It is what I thought. According to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases these versions 8-9 are very old. So why do they speak about these old versions if version 16 is released ?

Comment: How often do you update a stand-alone documentation of your software ;) Ver 8.x is from 2020 so just 3 years without update of the documentation...

Comment: Good job Facebook :)

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue or bug with versions `13.0.0` | `16.0.0` | `16.2.0` .. the issue solved only with version `15.2.0` .. the rest will show need upgrade warning